# Calculating the available space in a block of memory

Tags: database, block, space

I have  problem to calculate how much space is  avaialble in a current block in C.
Assume that  in a block we store records( the size of the record is known). And the space of a block is 512 bytes.
So if i want to check if a record fits in the block how will i calculate it ?
To calculate if it fits, i must know the available space of the current block,but i cant think a way to do this.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I found it . I just stored the number of records in the first block as metadata. And each time that i wanted to check the available space i was checking  (records%capacity_of_block.)